# Why does Sonarqube mark try as a critical issue?

Tags: maven, kotlin, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, ktorm

I'm currently facing an issue with some SonarQube's analysis being performed over some Kotlin code I wrote.

I'm trying to implement a method that connects to the database and returns accordingly to the query's result. I'm not sure how related this can be, but I added the following maven dependencies to my project:

- [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io)
- [Arrow](https://arrow-kt.io)
- [Ktorm](https://www.ktorm.org)

The code is the following:

```kotlin
@ApplicationScoped
class Repository(private val database: Database) {
    override fun get(name: String): Either<Error, Brand> =
        try {
            database.brands.find { it.name eq name }.rightIfNotNull {
                MissingBrandError("Missing brand")
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Either.Left(DatabaseError(e.message))
        }
}

class Error(val message: String)
class MissingUserError(val message: String) : Error(message)
class DatabaseError(val message: String? = null) : Error(message ?: "Some database error")
```

**NOTE**: Database object is of type org.ktorm.database.Database and brands is of type org.ktorm.entity.EntitySequence

The code is working and I also wrote unit tests for it that pass and give enough coverage (accordingly to the code coverage analysis tool), but at some point in my pipeline SonarQube marks the *try* as a critical issue with the following message:

> Possible null pointer dereference in (...)Repository(String) due to return value of called method

I checked it online and I could find some related questions, but none of the provided answers worked for me. Amongst the many attempts these are the ones I can remember I tried without any success:

1. Not inlining any code (pretty much using Java style code)
2. Extracting the query result to a variable
3. Check with if/else statements for nullability instead (both with inlined try and without)

I'd also like to highlight that all I can see on Sonar is the generated report and CLI for the running build. I don't have access to any of its configuration or intended to change them (unless of course it comes down to that). The line I mentioned seems to be the only one affected by this problem according to Sonar's report, that's why this is the solo class I provided.

I hope I provided enough info and that any of you can help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sonar has many bugs in this area and kotlin is a new world for it too... so it's probably a bug. Also the Kotlin compiler is very good at null checks, which points at a bug in sonar.

Comment: I think I'll keep a close eye on possible solutions/support for Kotlin and just suppress it for now. Thanks for the input!